# Is there a way to detect the first time networking is run in linux after the computer starts?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-networking

Is there a way to detect the first time networking is run?

I am referring to the very first time after the computer is started up, rather than when it is installed, ie networking has already been configured, but I need a post-up routine to determine that it is the first time of bringing up the network interfaces at boot time, rather than subsequent restarts by an administrator via /etc/init.d/networking or other means.

I am on Ubuntu Hardy.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you try re-wording your question? I can't make out what you are asking.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to find out from first run. i don't see any special significance of first run, that can't undone or redone.

Comment: For the first time it was run on startup. Use "uptime". But if you need to know when the "exactly this" configuration applied, I can't help you...

Comment: Im not sure what you want here, but cron @reboot feature may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you try to accomplish and it is possible that your goal can be achieved in a simpler way than what you've envisioned.

Anyhow, the simplest idea that I can think of is to add to your shutdown scripts one that does `rm /var/lock/net.first`. Then add `touch /var/lock/net.first` to your `rc.local`.

Then modify your network startup scripts to check for presence of this lock file. If it does not exists, it means, that the network is being brought up between a shutdown and execution of `rc.local`, which is the last of `rc` scripts being run at system boot.